# PostFX2 Custom Effect's Y position has wrong offset ONLY in GAME camera. Scene camera is OK

Tags: unity, fragment-shader, raymarching

I implemented raymarching in a full-screen Post FX2 custom effect.

Let's say I'm rendering a SDF sphere at world coordinates 0, 0, 0. Everything is fine in the scene camera -- if I rotate the camera in any direction, the SDF sphere retains its position at 0, 0, 0 and looks natural. For example -- if I am looking directly at the sphere and then look up by about 10 degrees, the sphere will then be naturally a bit closer to the bottom of the camera.

However, in the GAME camera, if I do that same exercise, the sphere is significantly lower. It seems like instead of being offset by the 10 or so degrees from the center, it may be about twenty. In essence, it seems like the camera's Y view direction is being doubled when rendering the pass...but it only does this for the game camera. Again, the scene camera is fine.

Here is the code:

RaymarchPostProcess.cs

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;

[Serializable]
public sealed class ShaderParameter : ParameterOverride<Shader> { }

[Serializable]
[PostProcess(typeof(RaymarchPostProcessRenderer), PostProcessEvent.BeforeStack, "Custom/RaymarchPostProcess")]
public sealed class RaymarchPostProcess : PostProcessEffectSettings
{
    public IntParameter maxIterations = new IntParameter { value = 64 };
    public FloatParameter maxDistance = new FloatParameter { value = 100f };
    public FloatParameter minDistance = new FloatParameter { value = 0.01f };

    public DepthTextureMode GetCameraFlags()
    {
        return DepthTextureMode.Depth; // DepthTextureMode.DepthNormals;
    }
}

public sealed class RaymarchPostProcessRenderer : PostProcessEffectRenderer<RaymarchPostProcess>
{
    Transform directionalLight;

    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();

        GameObject light = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainLight");

        if (light)
            directionalLight = light.transform;
    }

    public override void Render(PostProcessRenderContext context)
    {
        Camera _cam = context.camera;

        var sheet = context.propertySheets.Get(Shader.Find("Raymarch/RaymarchHDRP"));
        sheet.properties.SetMatrix("_CamFrustum", FrustumCorners(_cam));
        sheet.properties.SetMatrix("_CamToWorld", _cam.cameraToWorldMatrix);
        sheet.properties.SetVector("_CamWorldSpace", _cam.transform.position);
        sheet.properties.SetInt("_MaxIterations", settings.maxIterations);
        sheet.properties.SetFloat("_MaxDistance", settings.maxDistance);
        sheet.properties.SetFloat("_MinDistance", settings.minDistance);

        if (directionalLight)
        {
            Vector3 position = directionalLight.forward;
            sheet.properties.SetVector("_LightDir", new Vector4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1));
        }

        context.command.BlitFullscreenTriangle(context.source, context.destination, sheet, 0);
    }

    private Matrix4x4 FrustumCorners(Camera cam)
    {
        Transform camtr = cam.transform;

        Vector3[] frustumCorners = new Vector3[4];
        cam.CalculateFrustumCorners(new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1),
        cam.farClipPlane, cam.stereoActiveEye, frustumCorners);

        Vector3 bottomLeft = camtr.TransformVector(frustumCorners[1]);
        Vector3 topLeft = camtr.TransformVector(frustumCorners[0]);
        Vector3 bottomRight = camtr.TransformVector(frustumCorners[2]);

        Matrix4x4 frustumVectorsArray = Matrix4x4.identity;
        frustumVectorsArray.SetRow(0, bottomLeft);
        frustumVectorsArray.SetRow(1, bottomLeft + (bottomRight - bottomLeft) * 2);
        frustumVectorsArray.SetRow(2, bottomLeft + (topLeft - bottomLeft) * 2);

        return frustumVectorsArray;
    }
}
```

raymarchHDRP.shader

````
Shader "Raymarch/RaymarchHDRP"
{

    SubShader
    {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            HLSLPROGRAM

            #pragma target 3.5

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            //#include "Packages/com.unity.postprocessing/PostProcessing/Shaders/StdLib.hlsl"
            //#include "HLSLSupport.cginc"
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            //TEXTURE2D_SAMPLER2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex);
            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture, sampler_CameraDepthTexture;
            half4 _MainTex_ST;
            uniform float4 _CamWorldSpace;
            uniform float4x4 _CamFrustum,  _CamToWorld;
            uniform int _MaxIterations;
            uniform float _MaxDistance;
            uniform float _MinDistance;
            uniform float3 _LightDir;
            float4 _Tint;

            uniform float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

            struct AttributesDefault
            {
                float3 vertex : POSITION;
                half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
             float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
             float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
             float2 texcoordStereo : TEXCOORD1;
             float4 ray : TEXCOORD2;
            };

            // Vertex manipulation
            float2 TransformTriangleVertexToUV(float2 vertex)
            {
                float2 uv = (vertex + 1.0) * 0.5;
                return uv;
            }

            v2f vert(AttributesDefault v  )
            {
                v2f o;
                v.vertex.z = 0.1;
                o.vertex = float4(v.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
                o.texcoord = TransformTriangleVertexToUV(v.vertex.xy);
                o.texcoordStereo = TransformStereoScreenSpaceTex(o.texcoord, 1.0);

                int index = (o.texcoord.x / 2) + o.texcoord.y;
                o.ray = _CamFrustum[index];

                return o;
            }

            float sdSphere(float3 position, float3 origin, float radius)
            {
                return distance(position, origin) - radius;
            }

            float distanceField(float3 p) {
                return sdSphere(p, float3(1, 0, 0), 2);
            }

            float3 getNormal(float3 p)
            {
                const float2 offset = float2(0.001, 0.0);

                float3 n = float3(
                    distanceField(p + offset.xyy) - distanceField(p - offset.xyy),
                    distanceField(p + offset.yxy) - distanceField(p - offset.yxy),
                    distanceField(p + offset.yyx) - distanceField(p - offset.yyx));

                return normalize(n);
            }


            fixed4 raymarching(float3 rayOrigin, float3 rayDirection, float depth) {
                fixed4 result = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
                float t = 0.01; // Distance Traveled from ray origin (ro) along the ray direction (rd)

                for (int i = 0; i < _MaxIterations; i++)
                {
                    if (t > _MaxDistance || t >= depth)
                    {
                        result = float4(rayDirection, 0); // color backround from ray direction for debugging
                        break;
                    }

                    float3 p = rayOrigin + rayDirection * t;    // This is our current position
                    float d = distanceField(p); // should be a sphere at (0, 0, 0) with a radius of 1
                    if (d <= _MinDistance) // We have hit something
                    {
                        // shading
                        float3 n = getNormal(p);
                        float light = dot(-_LightDir, n);
                        result = float4(fixed3(1, 1, 1) * light, 1); // yellow sphere should be drawn at (0, 0, 0)
                        break;
                    }

                    t += d;
                }

                return result;
            }

            float4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                i.texcoord.y = 1 - i.texcoord.y;
                float4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                float depth = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture, UnityStereoTransformScreenSpaceTex(i.texcoord));
                depth = Linear01Depth(depth);
                depth *= length(i.ray);

                float3 rayOrigin = _CamWorldSpace;
                float3 rayDirection = normalize(i.ray);
                float4 result = raymarching(rayOrigin, rayDirection, depth);

                return fixed4(col * (1.0 - result.w) + result.xyz * result.w, 1.0);
            }

            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score -1):

Fixed. PEBCAK. It is always PEBCAK.

I had the camera transform's Y scale set to 0.33 while the X and Z were set to 1. Have a great day.

*plays lincoln park in shower*